# Create Linux DMA Buffer > 4 Megabytes

Tags: memory-management, linux-device-driver, dma

Using dma_alloc_coherent I can create driver DMA buffers up to 4 Megabytes in size. If I try to allocate anything larger than 4 MB, dma_alloc_coherent fails.

I would really like to create buffers up to 8 MB in size.

My questions:

1. Why does the 4 MB limit exist?
2. What is the best practices method to make DMA buffers of up to 8 MB?

Background: this is for a UIO driver on x86_64 architecture

Comment: Because it's quite hard on some architectures to find a DMA capable memory of such sizes. Anyway, you can allocate as many pages as you want and map them one-by-one.

Comment: You can use the `cma` kernel command-line parameter to change the size and location of the contiguous memory from which coherent allocations are made.